# Color as the third axis in seaborn jointplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, jointplot

I have three quantities, `x, y, z`, which I would like to see the distribution of two of them and have the value of the third one as color of each point. I use `seaborn.jointplot` to plot distributions of `x` and `y` and use the `z` as the color parameter in the `jointplot`. But, still I need to change the color palette and add a colorbar somewhere outside the plot. This is a minimal example of what I did:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)
y = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)
z = x**2  + y**2

plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(8, 5))
sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, c=z, joint_kws={"color":None})
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

by "changing the color palette", do you mean changing the colormap? If so, that can be done simply by passing the relevant info to `joint_kws`:

```py
g = sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, c=z, joint_kws={"color":None, 'cmap':'viridis'})
```

For the colorbar, it all depends on where you want it. Here is a solution that lets the axes to be resized automatically in order to make room. See [the documentation for `colorbar()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=colorbar#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar) to adjust the parameters as needed:

```py
g.fig.colorbar(g.ax_joint.collections[0], ax=[g.ax_joint, g.ax_marg_y, g.ax_marg_x], use_gridspec=True, orientation='horizontal')
```

full code:

```
plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(8, 5))
g = sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, c=z, joint_kws={"color":None, 'cmap':'viridis'})
g.fig.colorbar(g.ax_joint.collections[0], ax=[g.ax_joint, g.ax_marg_y, g.ax_marg_x], use_gridspec=True, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

[image]